# Waiting for an async call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I'm using the [`chrome.experimental.webRequest.onBeforeRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.webRequest.html#event-onBeforeRequest) callback where I need to find the URL of the tab making the request before returning from `onBeforeRequest`.

This would usually be the referring URL in the HTTP request but I also want the URL where there is no referrer sent such as HTTPS to HTTP requests.

The only thing I found was [`chrome.tabs.get`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/tabs.html#method-get) which is asynchronous.

What would be the best approach to get the tab URL before returning?

I have two ideas on solving this:

1. Using something similar to `ManualResetEvent`, though [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1131427/33236) says it is not possible.
2. Listen to some other event and record each tab URL in a local structure.

Comment: @DeependerSingla your comment does not make any sense, please explain where and why it matters here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any good answer to this, except the local structure you offered, and perhaps also using Web Workers, but that seems like an overkill, even if possible.